# Service not available when I try to get address from Geocoder in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Sometimes I get the IOException when I try to get address through latitude and longitude via the geocoder class of android.

This occurs rarely and force closes my application.

```
  private void locAdd(double latitude, double longitude) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ReportActivity.this,
            Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                longitude, 1);
        Log.e("Addresses", "-->" + addresses);
            } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to get location. Is there any issue with the code?
How do I solve it?

Logcat

```
   java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
   at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
   at com.pstpl.crimeverify.CrimeReportActivity.locAdd(CrimeReportActivity.java:554)
   at com.pstpl.crimeverify.CrimeReportActivity.access$10(CrimeReportActivity.java:549)
```

Comment: you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in the manifest file?

Answer (score -1):

The API documentation,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29

says that IOException will occur "if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs".

I don't think there is any problem with the code, since it works for "sometimes".

BTW, you are passing latitude1 and longitude as method arguments, but you are using latitude and longitude.

Comment: ohh yes sorry that was the mistake.... I have both GPS and network enabled but still same

Comment: Enabling network doesn't means that it is available all the time.

Comment: So then what is the solution?

Comment: You can try for three times and still it is not getting, inform the user (or take necessary error handling actions, depending upon the application requirements)

also look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11928881/721597

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641346/java-io-ioexception-unable-to-parse-response-from-server-geocoder for more solutions