# Getting Location information using latitude and longitude in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

**what i am trying to do**::

- I am trying to get the `location name` using the `Latitude` &
  `Longitude`
- I have made the key and added to manifest also
- I have updated the internet permission & other required permissions
  also
- I also have pushed the latitude & Longitude to emulator also

---

**I have added the project to DropBox** :: [Anyone can refer here Download & execute](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wh2uru69etaa0r/AddressFromLatLong.rar)

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        private EditText result;
        private Button btngetAddress;
        private Context context=null;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
            context=this;

            result=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_result);
            btngetAddress=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_getAddress);
            btngetAddress.setOnClickListener(this);


        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Please wait..", true);
            GetCurrentAddress currentadd=new GetCurrentAddress();
               currentadd.execute();
        }


        public  String getAddress(Context ctx, double latitude, double longitude) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);

                    String locality=address.getLocality();
                    String city=address.getCountryName();
                    String region_code=address.getCountryCode();
                    String zipcode=address.getPostalCode();
                    double lat =address.getLatitude();
                    double lon= address.getLongitude();

                    result.append(locality+" ");
                    result.append(city+" "+ region_code+" ");
                    result.append(zipcode);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }

            return result.toString();
        }

        private class GetCurrentAddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // this lat and log we can get from current location but here we given hard coded
                double latitude=12.9183555;
                double longitude=77.6702357;

            String address= getAddress(context, latitude, longitude);
                return address;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String resultString) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                result.setText(resultString);

            }
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_getAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Get Address" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**manifest::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.addressfromlatlong"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sunil.address.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

     <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBzReOb6cYRWordd-G1i7sd5N92Sy_H054" />

</manifest>
```

**Updated-Log**::

```
   04-16 13:15:35.377: D/dalvikvm(92): GC_EXPLICIT freed 465K, 11% free 12191K/13575K, paused 9ms+23ms
04-16 13:15:35.517: D/PackageManager(92): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
04-16 13:15:35.708: D/PackageManager(92): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
04-16 13:15:35.727: D/BackupManagerService(92): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.addressfromlatlong flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=201 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=151 violation=2
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1074)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1557)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.purgeOldGrants(AccountManagerService.java:224)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService.access$000(AccountManagerService.java:76)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.accounts.AccountManagerService$1.onReceive(AccountManagerService.java:213)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 13:15:35.757: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:744)
04-16 13:15:35.788: I/AccountTypeManager(278): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 178ms(wall) 16ms(cpu)
04-16 13:15:35.837: D/PackageManager(92): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
04-16 13:15:35.858: D/PackageManager(92): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
04-16 13:15:36.317: D/BackupManagerService(92): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.addressfromlatlong flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
04-16 13:15:36.317: V/BackupManagerService(92): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.example.addressfromlatlong
04-16 13:15:36.477: I/AccountTypeManager(278): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 407ms(wall) 12ms(cpu)
04-16 13:15:37.078: W/RecognitionManagerService(92): no available voice recognition services found
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=1107 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=151 violation=2
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1074)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:94)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.internal.os.AtomicFile.startWrite(AtomicFile.java:59)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.AppWidgetService.saveStateLocked(AppWidgetService.java:1181)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.AppWidgetService$2.onReceive(AppWidgetService.java:1452)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 13:15:38.247: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:744)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=1073 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=151 violation=1
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1048)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:178)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:447)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flushBytes(FastXmlSerializer.java:212)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flush(FastXmlSerializer.java:233)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.endDocument(FastXmlSerializer.java:183)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.AppWidgetService.writeStateToFileLocked(AppWidgetService.java:1240)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.AppWidgetService.saveStateLocked(AppWidgetService.java:1182)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.AppWidgetService$2.onReceive(AppWidgetService.java:1452)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:744)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=1065 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=151 violation=1
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1048)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.fsync(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(FileDescriptor.java:71)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.FileUtils.sync(FileUtils.java:111)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.internal.os.AtomicFile.finishWrite(AtomicFile.java:80)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.AppWidgetService.saveStateLocked(AppWidgetService.java:1183)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.AppWidgetService$2.onReceive(AppWidgetService.java:1452)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 13:15:38.317: D/StrictMode(92):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:744)
04-16 13:15:38.338: D/BackupManagerService(92): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.example.addressfromlatlong flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
04-16 13:15:38.338: V/BackupManagerService(92): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.example.addressfromlatlong
04-16 13:15:39.437: D/dalvikvm(92): GC_CONCURRENT freed 471K, 10% free 12310K/13575K, paused 12ms+133ms
04-16 13:15:41.133: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_CONCURRENT freed 363K, 5% free 10129K/10631K, paused 2134ms+56ms
04-16 13:15:43.257: D/dalvikvm(1022): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1421K, 28% free 14502K/19975K, paused 133ms
04-16 13:15:44.617: D/dalvikvm(92): GC_EXPLICIT freed 216K, 11% free 12185K/13575K, paused 1612ms+76ms
04-16 13:15:44.687: D/AndroidRuntime(1073): Shutting down VM
04-16 13:15:44.727: I/AndroidRuntime(1073): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-16 13:15:44.757: D/dalvikvm(1073): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 454K/2048K, paused 3ms+4ms
04-16 13:15:44.777: D/jdwp(1073): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
04-16 13:15:44.787: D/dalvikvm(1073): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-16 13:15:45.847: D/AndroidRuntime(1094): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-16 13:15:45.857: D/AndroidRuntime(1094): CheckJNI is ON
04-16 13:15:47.667: D/AndroidRuntime(1094): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-16 13:15:47.758: I/ActivityManager(92): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.addressfromlatlong/com.sunil.address.MainActivity} from pid 1094
04-16 13:15:47.797: W/WindowManager(92): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
04-16 13:15:47.887: D/AndroidRuntime(1094): Shutting down VM
04-16 13:15:47.947: I/AndroidRuntime(1094): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-16 13:15:47.987: D/dalvikvm(1094): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 77% free 483K/2048K, paused 2ms+43ms
04-16 13:15:47.987: D/jdwp(1094): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
04-16 13:15:47.987: D/dalvikvm(1094): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-16 13:15:48.047: D/dalvikvm(1105): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-16 13:15:48.087: I/ActivityManager(92): Start proc com.example.addressfromlatlong for activity com.example.addressfromlatlong/com.sunil.address.MainActivity: pid=1105 uid=10047 gids={3003, 1015}
04-16 13:15:48.117: I/WindowManager(92): createSurface Window{41510cd0 Starting com.example.addressfromlatlong paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
04-16 13:15:48.747: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(92): setKernelCountSet(10047, 1) failed with errno -2
04-16 13:15:50.117: I/WindowManager(92): createSurface Window{41600328 com.example.addressfromlatlong/com.sunil.address.MainActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
04-16 13:15:50.277: D/gralloc_goldfish(1105): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-16 13:15:50.487: I/ActivityManager(92): Displayed com.example.addressfromlatlong/com.sunil.address.MainActivity: +2s601ms
04-16 13:15:51.018: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(92): setKernelCountSet(10005, 0) failed with errno -2
04-16 13:15:54.527: I/WindowManager(92): createSurface Window{416690e8 com.example.addressfromlatlong/com.sunil.address.MainActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
04-16 13:15:55.458: W/InputManagerService(92): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4150df50
```

---

**Still i am not able to get the information i need**, ***How to resolve this***

Comment: Are you getting any error?if yes,then post your logcat.

Comment: @kgandroid .... there is no error , but i have posted the log....please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6922448/2771869

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
List<String>  providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
if(null!=locations && null!=providerList && providerList.size()>0){                 
double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());                 
try {
    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
        String _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me.

Put the below code just below the setContentView() in your activity.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
```

If error comes after saving your application then just mouseover the error and add  @SuppressLint("NewApi")(Eclipse will give you option on mouse over).For example you will get an error on the word "build".Inform me if it works.

Comment: Please Look at the updated Log (I followed your steps)....... Everything looks correct still why i am not able to get the O/p .... dont know .... I am using emulator(I dont have a device)...... Any ideas

Comment: is your map showing??The last thing I can suggest is do not use the getaddress method(which you have written),rather put the content of the getaddress() method in doinbackground().Debug your application and see what is the value of the String "address".

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is an exception:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
}
```

This will print : `tag : Service not available` in your logcat. To solve this problem follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087601/service-not-available-when-i-try-to-get-address-from-geocoder-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641346/java-io-ioexception-unable-to-parse-response-from-server-geocoder)

Go to Location settings and enable:

1. Use Wireless networks
2. Use GPS satellites